# How to sort order by descending in mongo query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to show recently added data in the collection from MongoDB.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please edit your question to show specifically what you're trying to do: example input data, expected output of query, query attempt, actual output/errors/etc. As written, there's really no way to know what you're having issues with. Plus, you tagged this as `node.js` - unless this is a programming question specific to node, it shouldn't be tagged as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [auto-generated-createdat-and-updatedat-fields-in-mongodb](https://medium.com/@iamlittlerock/auto-generated-createdat-and-updatedat-fields-in-mongodb-86bb5980be2), then use the [$orderby](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/) operator to order it descending.
It may be worth it to add an index on those fields if you expect your table to grow.

```
db.collection.find().sort( { age: -1 } )
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions that have no specific detail. As written, the question is really a documentation request. Best to comment to the OP to ask for more details, rather than posting documentation content and links.